# How to set limited permissions using command line on windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, icacls

user want to delete all permissions and keep only modify permission for everyone and full permission to system.
Like this.

[image: 1]

But present with icacls command

```
icacls "%ProgramData%\myfolder\Licensing" /grant Everyone:M SYSTEM:F
```

[image: 2]

how to remove all other entries and keep only this.

[image: 3]

whether icacls or any other command line

I tried

```
icacls "%ProgramData%\myfolder\Licensing" /grant Everyone:M SYSTEM:F /inheritance:r
```

But it is not setting like that.

Comment: You need to provide the output of the command and resulting permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This target [Page](https://winscripting.wordpress.com/2022/11/24/cacls-to-give-permissions-only-to-everyone-and-system/) contains the output you expecting using cacls command